# "We'll do it in a..."

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography

Today in my mathematics class my lecturer used a phrase I am very familiar with, and I suspect many others may be familiar with too.  However, when thinking about how one would write a particular word in this phrase I became perplexed, and am wondering if anyone else knows how to write it.

The phrase is:

"We'll do the final few steps in a one-ner."

The final word is written as it is pronounced.  Are others familiar with this word, and does anyone know how it would be written? I doubt it's in the dictionary (I've checked under multiple potential spellings), but it seems to be a common word (I am Scottish, so perhaps this is a regional question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_a_one-er) has the following entry:

> **in a one-er** (not comparable)
>   (*informal*) in one attempt
>   *You can probably empty your glass in a one-er, there's not much left.*

*[In a oner](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_a_oner)* is given as an alternative form, and [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oner) has *oner*.  I would tend to go with *oner*, since (1) it looks more authentic, (2) it's in the Oxford Dictionary, and (3) *one-er* reminds me of an uninformed person's attempt at translating it from spoken to written English.

It appears to be a British term, which is probably why I wasn't familiar with it.

The only way I can possibly make a stab at guessing which is more popular is by Google, so the rest of this answer isn't worth all that much...  ["in a oner"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22in%20a%20oner%22#q=%22in%20a%20oner%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=LfNXT5eTI-rr0gGqhrC5Dw&start=438&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95e6f5d098e4da22&biw=1366&bih=643) has 448 results and ["in a one-er"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22in%20a%20one-er%22#q=%22in%20a%20one-er%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=HPNXT9mWO-L10gGnuvibDw&start=346&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95e6f5d098e4da22&biw=1366&bih=643) has 356.

Comment: Many thanks, were you previously familiar with this term?

Comment: Nope, but I am now.  You've taught me at least as much as I taught you.

Comment: I am surprised. You didn't know the expression before, you quote a highly restrictive (and therefore misleading) definition from Wiktionary, and it gets accepted with the highest number of upvotes. Chambers, for example, (also British) gives *a person or thing unique or outstanding in any way: an expert: a heavy blow: a big lie*. All of which I as a Brit am familiar with. The *only* usage I know where it has any sense of "attempt" is exactly your example - to down a drink in one go, without taking the glass/cup from your lips.

Answer (score 5):

From OED:

**oner** - *2 colloq. Something consisting of, denoted by, or in some way characterized by the number one. spec. one pound; one hundred pounds.*

I suppose in your context, the lecturer either meant a *one-liner* (he'd write a one-line expression implementing the final few steps/calculations on the blackboard), or that he'd go through the final steps in a single uninterrupted section of his presentation, without pausing to allow questions, etc.

Comment: The last time I heard *oner* it referred to a conker (that had defeated precisely one other), so I wouldn't say it's common.

Comment: @TimLymington: haha - that was the first usage that came to mind for me too, so I'm going back half a century there. But in later years I did sometimes hear/use it myself to mean **one hundred pounds**, in respect of a "moonlighting" job where one might give up a day at the weekend to do something relatively well paid. *"Can you give me a hand next Saturday to fit a recon engine in so-and-so's Mini Cooper? It's worth a oner."*